# где посмотреть все макросы postgre?

Tags: postgresql

Нужно написать расширение для postgres. В примерах кода в интернете постоянно мелькают макросы типа `PG_GETARG_INT32`, `PG_FUNCTION_ARGS`, функции `pq_getmsgfloat8`, `palloc`. Где можно посмотреть весь их список и пояснения? Гугление не помогает(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Doxygen* проекта *PostgreSQL* находится тут:
https://doxygen.postgresql.org/.
Вот например ссылка на `PG_GETARG_INT32`:
https://doxygen.postgresql.org/fmgr_8h.html#ab57a397490a372982886c76b5f16a295.

Comment: а есть место, где явно поясняют, что для чего?

Comment: Я не видел.  Возможно, коллеги добавят.  Пока могу только порекомендовать читать код.